# Creating an overlay view and render it in a dynamic div in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

Here is the the framework I have:

....

```
var showChart = new showChartView({
    el: this.$el.find("#my-chart-div");
    // Other parameters passed in to build the chart
});
showChart.render();
```

The above view renders a chart graph on the browser.

The css for the div above looks like:

```
my-chart-div
{
    height: 100,
    width: 300
}
```

The html:

```
<div id="my-chart-div"></div>
```

What I want to do is that when I hover over the div (my-chart-div), there should be an overlaying chart rendered in a bigger size (rendered as an instance of the same view above - ShowChartView but with larger width and height), so the css of that would look something like:

```
overlay-chart-div
{
    height: 200,
    width: 500
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your question about detecting the hover or showing an overlay? Please add the remaining configs that are currently hidden behind `// Other parameters passed in to build the char`.

Comment: Detecting the hover and showing the overlay, both can be achieved by the :hover in css - see answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want a slightly bigger chart when you hover over it?

If that is the case this should work perfectly for you:

```
#my-chart-div:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1) translate(4%, 4%);
}
```

For bigger just up the scale() to 1.2.

Comment: This worked. However, the overlayed chart on the leftmost corner gets cropped because looks like the transform applies centrally. I am sure there is a way to position the larger chart but haven't figured it yet. Thanks @Nealime

Comment: I updated my awnser with a possible fix for the positioning of the larger element. You might need to fiddle a little with the % values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mouse events(mouseenter, mouseleave) to perform this:

```html
events: {
'mouseenter #my-chart-div' : 'show_overlay',
'mouseleave #' : 'hide_overlay',
},

show_overlay: function(event){
  // show the overlay div, load/copy bigger chart...
},

hide_overlay: function(event){
  // restore it here or simply call the render function
},
```

Regarding the overlay content, you can always use the same content or copy it from my-chart-div (jquery detach() function), or if the chart needs to be preloaded with the new dimensions, you just call the chart rendering function in the overlay element

Answer (score 0):

So, for making the element "my-chart-div" 1.1 times larger on hover, simply add the following code to the css for the element:

```
#my-chart-div:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Above solution works to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please add some more details as to how this answer solves the problem.  Small answer containing only code may be difficult to understand for new users